# Django - Filter objects from child class with parent class primary key passed in URL

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to pass all the Posts made for each vehicle in a vehicle detail html page.

My vehicles/models.py:

```
*vehicles/models.py*

class Vehicle(models.Model):

     
    TESLA = 'TESLA'
    MAZDA = 'MAZDA'
    VOLVO = 'VOLVO'
    VEHICLE_CHOICES = (
        (TESLA, "Tesla"),
        (MAZDA, "Mazda"),
        (VOLVO, "Volvo"),
        )

    owner =  models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    
    model = models.CharField(max_length=9,
       
                    choices=VEHICLE_CHOICES,
                    default=TESLA)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.model

    class Meta:
        db_table = "vehicles"
```

My Posts models.py:

```
*blog/models.py*

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


     
class Post(models.Model):
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vehicle =  models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None )
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):

        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs ={'pk': self.pk} )
  
    class Meta:
        db_table = "chargehistory"
```

I am already passing in a html file all the Vehicles for each User and now i would like to get all the posts made for each User's vehicle.

```
*vehicles/views.py*

class UserVehicleListView(ListView):
    model = Vehicle
    template_name = 'vehicles/vehicles.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'vehicles'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Vehicle.objects.filter(owner_id= self.request.user.id)

class UserVehicleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Vehicle
```

```
*vehicles/urls.py*



urlpatterns = [
    path('vehicles', UserVehicleListView.as_view(), name='vehicle-list'),
    path('vehicles/<int:pk>',  UserVehicleDetailView.as_view() , name='vehicle-detail'),

]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Since i'm passing the vehicle primary key in the path, is there any way for me to filter the posts based on that key and pass it to vehicle_detail.html? Should i pass it as a ListView in the same path as UserVehicleDetailView?

Comment: Please note that the sequence of url matching patterns is important: Whenever an url starts with `vehicles` the first url will match. If you want to call `vehicles/3` you need to change the sequence in the `urls.py`

Comment: Special Note: Change field name from `model` to `vehicle_type` or something else or else it will clash somehow may be later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly use [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview)<sup>[django-doc]</sup> as used by you. Your `route` for `DetailView` in urls.py is correct. You must have to pass its pk from from html part.

views.py

```py
class UserVehicleDetailView(DetailView):
    model=Vehicle
    template_name="any_folder_name/any_file.html"
    context_object_name="single_vehicle"
```

> `Note:` While using `DetailView` you should not run loop, as it is a single object.

anyfile.html

```html
{% if "single_vehicle" %}
    <p>{{single_vehicle.owner.username}}</p>
{% endif %}
```

Here, you can access all his properties by chaining, and you can also change `pk` to another name say, `id` and then mentioned it in your `UserVehicleDetailView` as  `pk_url_kwarg="id"`, then also it will work.

But at first, you need to pass `pk` through `ListView` through loop and then access it as a single object through `DetailView`.

> `Note:` Always give `/` at the end of every route in path function.

---

---

---

### Here is minimal reproducible example:

Create, a simple project in which make an app called `home`, register it in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`. After that see below example:

models.py

```py
from django.db import models

class Subject(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.AllStudentDetailView.as_view(), name='all_student_detail'),
    path('single_student/<int:id>/',
         views.SingleStudentView.as_view(), name='student_detail')
]
```

views.py

```py
from msilib.schema import ListView
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from .models import Student


class AllStudentDetailView(ListView):
    model = Student
    template_name = 'home/list_of_students.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_students'


class SingleStudentView(DetailView):
    model = Student
    template_name = 'home/single_student.html'
    context_object_name = 'student'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'id'
```

> `Note:` In `DetailView` there is also use of `pk_url_kwarg`, this is used when we give something else than `pk`.

admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Student, Subject


@admin.register(Subject)
class SubjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name']


@admin.register(Student)
class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'email', 'father_name', 'subject']
```

list_of_students.html

```html
<body>
    <h2>All Student Details</h2>
    <table border='1' style='text-align:center;' cellpadding='3px' cellspacing='3px'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Father Name</th>
                
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for student in all_students  %}
            <tr>
                <td><a href="{% url 'student_detail' student.id %}">{{student.name}}</a></td>
                <td>{{student.email}}</td>
                <td>{{student.father_name}}</td>

            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>

    </table>
</body>
```

single_student.html

```html
<body>
    {% if student %}
    <h2>Detail of {{student.name}}</h2>
    <h3>All subject he/she had taken are:</h3>

    <p>Subject is -- {{student.subject}}</p>

    {% else %}
    <p>Student object does not come.</p>
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

When you click on single student's name, you are redirected to see its detail on detail page.

Comment: But how can i pass the posts to anyfile.html which the vehicle.id is the one i passed in urls?

Comment: @boytoyzip Can you share your code?

Comment: @boytoy.zip Do you want me to show you a full example using `DetailView` and `ListView`?

Comment: I just have a question, based on your example, a subject can have multiple students, so the subject is the parent class. Imagine the scenario where you wanted to get all the students who attend the subject with the id passed in urls, as in you have an html page for the subject maths which has id=1 and you wanted to get all the students with that foreign key in the same html file?

Comment: In the example, i have shown a student can have more than one subject, here ManyToOne relation is with Student, yes you can also show those students related to particular subject through the query `Student.objects.filter(subject='English')`, it will give queryset containing all those students which have taken english as a subject. There is pdf of django doc, almost about 2300 pages, you should read it.